# solving PDE equation like Helmholtz equation in 1D

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In my project I need to solve following equation analytically  could anyone help me ? As I read the other questions, my equation seems like   Helmholtz equation
$$
     \triangledown^2 u(x) - k_cu(x) =0 \quad  \\
       u(0) = 1
    \quad x \in [0,L] ,   $$

Comment: A linear PDE, with constant coefficients, and what appears to be periodic boundary conditions (at least in one of the variables, but I think there is a typo: the notations $u(x)$, $u(x, 0)$, and $u(0, x)$ are inconsistent: is $x$ the first variable or the second one?).  Also, you need to clarify what $\Omega$ is.

Have you tried the Fourier transform in the periodic variable?

Comment: sorry it was typo error. I corrected it

Comment: Now you don't have enough boundary conditions to specify a unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition of the Laplace-operator in 1-D you get that:

\begin{align*}
 u''(x) = k_c u(x)
\end{align*}
This equation has three possible solutions depending on the sign of $k_c$-

If $k_c>0$ the solution is:
\begin{align*}
 u(x) = C_1e^{\sqrt{k_c}x}+C_2 e^{-\sqrt{k_c}x}
\end{align*}
Now inserting your initial value we have the constraint that $C_1+C_2 =1$.

If $k_c<0$ the solution is:
\begin{align*}
 u(x) = C_1\sin({\sqrt{-k_c}x})+C_2 \cos({\sqrt{-k_c}x})
\end{align*}
Again inserting your initial condition we have the constraint $C_2=1$.

If $k_c=0$ well that is left as an exercise ;o)